# Whatsapp api taking up to 30 minutes to deliver message

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm new to the meta business platform. I'm currently setting up a whatsapp business account to send messages programaticaly. I'm able to use the api to send messages and make use of templates. The problem is that the messages are being delivered, but with a delay of over 30 minutes.

The api endpoint I'm using is [https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{{](https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/%7B%7B) _.phoneId }}/messages

Is there any settings required to make them be delivered as fast as possible?

Comment: Try a template message without parameters and see if you have the same issue I am having., see below

Answer (score 3):

There's an active bug in the Meta cloud API which is causing this delay. You can track it here - https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/587271766844244/

Answer (score -2):

No there is no fast service possible however

To reduce message delivery delays on the WB API

Optimize your server processing time and infrastructure for efficient handling of API requests.

Comment: I'm not hosting anything, I'm using Meta's cloud api. I call the api, receive the 200 Ok code, and after 30 minutes, the message arrives in my cellphone. Is the On-Premises API more reliable and faster?